# Dojo 2 How can I destroy dojo 2 widget manually?

Tags: dojo2

This question is specific to Dojo 2 not dojo 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dojo, how destroy a custom widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557336/dojo-how-destroy-a-custom-widget)

Comment: @AnikoLitvanyi My question is for Dojo 2 not dojo 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onDetach is called when a widget is removed from the widget tree and therefore the DOM. onDetach is called recursively down the tree to ensure that even if a widget at the top of the tree is removed all the child widgets onDetach callbacks are fired.

```
class MyClass extends WidgetBase {
  onDetach() {
    // do things when removed from the DOM
  }
}
```